# Are Sortable inlines on Grappelli applicable for M2M fields?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield, django-grappelli, sortables

I can't seem to get the sortable inlines feature (in grappelli) work for me.

I'm starting to wonder if the feature is not supported for `ManyToManyField`s or if I am not getting it right.

Also, is there a sample code out there so I can see and learn? I already followed the method described [here](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#inline-sortables).

Comment: [How about this](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#related-lookups)?

Comment: Isn't that lookups? I am not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M2M Fields didn't work for me. But, turns out there's a work-around for this.

I created a `through` model for a `ManyToManyField` and added `order` in that `through` model. Remember, the `through` model uses `ForeignKey` fields. So, the case essentially becomes that of managing a couple of one-to-many relationships.

Implementing sortable inlines is now as easy as following Grappelli's documentation.